# 2d array struct giving a segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, 2d

This program fragment should be reading in information in structs which are stored in a 2d way.
But this program fragment gives a segmentation fault after "printf("lel4\n");".
I have the feeling it is in my memory allocation, but I don't know. I looked for answers on the internet and I am doing exactly the same thing as the given answers, but it isn't working.

```
typedef struct coordinates{ 
    int xposition;                          
    int ypositiony;                         
    char token;                     
    int discovered;                 
} coordinates

typedef coordinates *coord;

coord **allocMemory(int row, int col){
    int i;
    coord **city = malloc(sizeof(coord)*col);
    assert(city != NULL);
    for(i=0; i<col; i++){
        city[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct coordinates)*row);
        assert(city[i] != NULL);
    }
    return city;
}


coord **readInfo(int row, int col){
    int i, j;
    char c;
    coord **city = allocMemory(row, col);
    for(i=0; i<col;i++){
        c = getchar();
        for(j = 0; j<ros; j++){
            c = getchar();
            if(c == '#' || c == '.'){
                printf("lel4\n");
                (*city)[i][j].xposition = i;
                printf("lel5\n");
                (*city)[i][j].yposition = j;
                (*city)[i][j].token = c;
                (*city)[i][j].discovered = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return city;
}
```

Comment: There is no 2D array in the code and no construct that can be used as one.

Comment: what is **city doing then?

Comment: `coord **` --> `coord *`

Comment: No offence (honestly!), but: As you have to ask means you don't really know what you do. I suspect you just follow some pattern. `coord **` is a pointer to pointer. If a pointer was the same as an array, it would not be called differently. There are already dozens of questions here about how to construct an N-D array. Just do some reading.

Comment: try rewrite code without `typedef coordinates *coord;`

Comment: I just don't like structs, they are kind of confusing, but I found the answer, thanks!

Comment: In extension to @BLUEPIXY comment: don't `typedef` pointers! That makes you code less readable. As does not using structured datatypes where appropriate. **Not** using them makes your code confusing, not the correct usage.

Comment: This is how they do it at my education. And if you do not use them you will get points subtracted :(. Atleast typedefing a struct to a *struct.

Comment: You cannot "`typedef` a `struct` to a `* struct`" (whatever the latter means). About the rest: go to a better school/university; your tutor can not properly program. Be carful getting used to that bad habit; you will have a hard time getting rid of it later in a job if your company has good coding style guides. The same when not getting used to `struct`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
coord **
```

to 
`coord *`

and

```
city[i][j].xposition = i;
city[i][j].yposition = j;
city[i][j].token = c;
city[i][j].discovered = 0;
```